# How can I load activity in android java?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load **activity2** from the main activity,
I debug the program and found that the program reached **activity2** but nothing happens,
the new activity doesn't invoke on the emulator.
The manifest looks OK.
The syntax looks OK.
What can be the reason ????

I tried few solutions but no success
thanks a lot

Thanks

```
// main activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    EditText etFname,etLname;
    Button btnlogin;
    Button btnsignup;
    Button btnhome;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnlogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);  //connect button to xml
        btnsignup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsignup);
        btnhome=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnhomescreen);
        etFname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFname);
        etLname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLname);
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnhome.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnsignup.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(btnlogin==v)
        {
            if (dataSending()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        if(btnsignup==v)
        {
            Intent i =new Intent(this,MainActivity3.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

        if(btnhome==v)
        {
            Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home_screen.class);
            startActivity(X);

        }
    }

    private boolean dataSending() {
        // Here comes the dataSending function

        JSONObject sendingData = new JSONObject();

        try {
            sendingData.put("request", "login");
            sendingData.put("user", etFname.getText().toString());
            sendingData.put("password", etLname.getText().toString());
            SocketTask dataTransportTask = new SocketTask(sendingData);
            JSONObject received = dataTransportTask.execute().get();
            String str1="";
            str1=received.get("response").toString();
            Toast.makeText(this,str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // JSONObject jObjResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
            return str1.equals("Hey there");
            //return str1.equals("Hey there");
        } catch (JSONException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
// activity2

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton japan;
    ImageButton china; Dialog c;
    ImageButton nepal; Dialog n;
    ImageButton thailand; Dialog t;
    ImageButton rusia; Dialog r;
    ImageButton maldives; Dialog m;
    ImageButton korea; Dialog k;
    ImageButton sriLanka; Dialog s;
    ImageButton india; Dialog i;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        china = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chinaImageButton);
        china.setOnClickListener(this);
        rusia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rusiaImageButton);
        rusia.setOnClickListener(this);
        japan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.japanImageButton);
        japan.setOnClickListener(this);
        nepal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nepalImageButton);
        nepal.setOnClickListener(this);
        thailand = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.thailandImageButton);
        thailand.setOnClickListener(this);
        maldives = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.maldivesImageButton);
        maldives.setOnClickListener(this);
        rusia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rusiaImageButton);
        rusia.setOnClickListener(this);
        india = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.indiaImageButton);
        india.setOnClickListener(this);
        korea = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.koreaImageButton);
        korea.setOnClickListener(this);
        sriLanka = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sriLankaImageButton);
        sriLanka.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


        public void createjapanDialog()
        {
            Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,japan_java.class);
            startActivity(X);
            /*Dialog j=new Dialog(this);
            j.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_japan);
            j.setCancelable(false);
            j.show();*/
        }


        public void createchinaDialog()
        {
            Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,china_java.class);
            startActivity(X);
            /*c=new Dialog(this);
            c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_china);
            c.setCancelable(false);
            c.show();*/
        }

    public void createnepalDialog()
    {
        Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,nepal_java.class);
        startActivity(X);
        /*c=new Dialog(this);
        c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_nepal);
        c.setCancelable(false);
        c.show();*/
    }

    public void createindiaDialog()
    {
        Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,india_java.class);
        startActivity(X);
        /*c=new Dialog(this);
        c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_india);
        c.setCancelable(false);
        c.show();*/
    }

    public void createmaldivesDialog()
    {
        Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,maldives_java.class);
        startActivity(X);
        /*c=new Dialog(this);
        c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_maldives);
        c.setCancelable(false);
        c.show();*/
    }

    public void createrusiaDialog()
    {
        Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,rusia_java.class);
        startActivity(X);
        /*c=new Dialog(this);
        c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_rusia);
        c.setCancelable(false);
        c.show();*/
    }

    public void createkoreaDialog()
    {
        Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,korea_java.class);
        startActivity(X);
        /*c=new Dialog(this);
        c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_korea);
        c.setCancelable(false);
        c.show();*/
    }

    public void createthailandDialog()
    {
        Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,thailand_java.class);
        startActivity(X);
        /*c=new Dialog(this);
        c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_thailand);
        c.setCancelable(false);
        c.show();*/
    }

    public void createsriLankaDialog()
    {
        Intent X =new Intent(MainActivity2.this,srilanka_java.class);
        startActivity(X);
        /*c=new Dialog(this);
        c.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_srilanka);
        c.setCancelable(false);
        c.show();*/
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (china == view)
            {
                createchinaDialog();
                }
            if (japan == view)
            {
                createjapanDialog();

            }
            if (nepal == view)
            {
                createnepalDialog();

            }
            if (india == view)
            {
                createindiaDialog();

            }
            if (korea == view)
            {
                createkoreaDialog();

            }
            if (maldives == view)
            {
                createmaldivesDialog();

            }
            if (rusia == view)
            {
                createrusiaDialog();

            }
            if (sriLanka == view)
            {
                createsriLankaDialog();

            }
            if (thailand == view)
            {
                createthailandDialog();

            }

            }






   }
```

```
// manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.il.myApp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".china_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".india_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".japan_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".korea_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".maldives_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".nepal_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".rusia_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".srilanka_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".thailand_java"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Home_screen"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity3"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have  you placed break point in onCreate method of MainActivity2?

Comment: it's just about MainActivity2 ??? or MainActivity3 too

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the `if` argument? Does `btnlogin==v` return True? You should try the following code so when the button is clicked, it will direct you to another activity.

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (dataSending()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        }
    });
```